# Android touch to configure

Tags: android, user-interface

I am writing a key management interface for an android app. I want to place an element at the top which shows the private key. I think an ExpandableListView with one element should do the trick, as I want to show the key details on touch.

But before there is a key, I would like instead to show an element that says "Touch to add private key". As I do not know what this is called, I am not getting good Google results. How should I go about implementing this? I imagine that I should have a container, and programmatically fill it with one or the other element based on the presence of a private key. Is there a best practice for this kind of thing?